# Python Project Structuring with unittest

Tags: python, python-unittest, project-structure

I'm practicing TDD in python and currently, my project has the following structure:

```
App
    A_folder
        init__.py
        core.py
        rand.csv
    B_folder
    test
        __init__.py
        test_A_folder
            __init__.py
            test_some_funtion_in_A_folder.py
```

In the test class, test_some_funtion_in_A_folder.py, I have a class name starting with Test* and all my tests have "test_" as the prefix. Yet I'm running into errors.

I'm running the test by including and clicking the play icon in PyCharm:

```
import unittest


class TestSomething(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_something(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Can I get some help? Thanks in advance.

```
My error output:
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.7.4, pytest-5.2.1, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.13.0 -- C:\Users\kroha\Anaconda3\python.exe
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: {Path}\App
plugins: arraydiff-0.3, doctestplus-0.4.0, openfiles-0.4.0, remotedata-0.3.2
collecting ... ERROR: not found: {Path}\App\test\test_A_folder\test_some_funtion_in_A_folder
(no name '{Path}\App\test\test_A_folder\test_some_funtion_in_A_folder' in any of [])

collected 0 items

============================ no tests ran in 0.01s ============================

Process finished with exit code 4

Empty suite
```

Comment: how do you execute the tests?

Comment: Please, attach code for `test_some_funtion_in_A_folder.py`. Might be just some typo mistake

Comment: Added those in the edits

Comment: "I'm running the test by including and clicking the play icon in PyCharm" Okay, and what happens if you try it from the command line?

Comment: A simple test case without any import is passing when I run it from the command line. However, when I add "from A_folder.core import something", I'm getting ModuleNotFoundError when executing from the command line.

Comment: what's `{Path}`? Apparently it's not substituted by anything, which is why you're getting "not found" error

Comment: The error contains the complete path; however, in the above message I replaced it as {Path} to hide few local directory path details.

Comment: the error message told u exactly what u need to know: ERROR: not found, so check ur path first. also you did not import the function to test in ur unittest code.